# Elixir Overloading Parameter with multiple Map and retry Repo.get_by()

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to overload a function that takes a map as a parameter for a few different cases. When calling the function, a different function will execute based on the keys in the map.

For example, in this `find_user!()` function, I can find the user by `id`, `email`, or `mobile` number fields which are all indexed in the database.

```
  def find_user!(%{"id" => user_id}) do
    Repo.get(User, user_id)
  end

  def find_user!(%{"email" => email}) do
    IO.puts "get user by email"
    Repo.get_by(User, email: email)
  end

  def find_user!(%{"mobile" => mobile}) do
    IO.puts "get user by mobile"
    Repo.get_by(User, mobile: mobile)
  end
```

Although, in this case I have both an `email` and a `mobile` number and I want to lookup the record in the database using the provided email and if it cannot be found, look it up by mobile number. If it cannot be found by both, it should return the standard `nil` or RecordNotFound exception.

```
  def find_user!(%{"email" => email, "mobile" => mobile } = params) do
    Enum.any?(params, fn(x,y) -> IO.puts "#{x} , #{y} " end )
    #Try finding by Email, then try finding by mobile
    # code goes here
  end
```

I started with the fields and began experimenting with the `Enum.any?` with a conditional to test if any retrieval for the map containing `email` and `mobile` but before I could get too far I realized that when I ran the `MyApplication.find_user!(%{ "email" => "admin@example.com","mobile" => "0009998888"})` function in the console, that the overloading went to the first overloaded `find_user!(%{"email" => email})` function instead of my function. I assume this is because it matched the field first.

Is there a way to overload a function in Elixir with a map of parameters like this? Or am I approaching this problem wrong? Maybe I should be using a recursive style function to do the initial try of looking up the record and then retry using a different attribute.

Comment: The order of the function heads is significant. You'll want the most specific one (the one with `%{"email" => email, "mobile" => mobile}`) defined first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do this, without adding anything to your first three functions:

```
  def find_user!(%{"id" => user_id}) do
    Repo.get(User, user_id)
  end

  def find_user!(%{"email" => email} = params) do
    IO.puts "get user by email, then mobile"
    case Repo.get_by(User, email: email) do
      nil -> Repo.get_by(User, mobile: params["mobile"])
      val -> val
    end
  end

  def find_user!(%{"mobile" => mobile}) do
    IO.puts "get user by mobile"
    Repo.get_by(User, mobile: mobile)
  end
```